# No class def found for the first time of accessing the class even when the related jar is available

Tags: java, jar, jboss, classpath, classnotfoundexception

Sample code snippet.

```
class Sample extends Test1 ,Test2
{
...
}
```

The class Sample is in `x_util.jar` and the class `Test2` is in `y_const.jar`.
Both the jars are in the same lib folder of JBoss.

**Problem**

When I am trying to access the class `Sample` for the first time it is throwing the error

> No Class def found

saying `Test2` is not defined.

If I am accessing it again then it is working fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: so... how did you manage to extend 2 classes?

Comment: sorry .... my mistake the sample is an interface an is extending two classes